# Data(bytes...) is deprecated. Rewrite

Tags: swift

Have this bit of code that I found that is part of an compression/decompression file. I was able to figure out how to update the unsafeBytes but I haven't found anything on how to update this bit of code:

```
var header = Data(bytes: [0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00]) // magic, magic, deflate, noflags
```

I receive the warning: init(bytes:) is deprecated: use init(_:) instead

Anyone know how to update this?

Comment: `Data([0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00])`

Comment: @MicahMontoya lol, we all have those days

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your code, you have used the `Data(bytes: [0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00])` initializer of `Data` which is the same as using `Data.init(bytes: [0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00])`. Since `init(bytes:)` is already deprecated, you are suggested to use the `init(_:)` initializer. Hence, your code should be:

```
var header = Data([0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00])
```